# An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I got error in the tittle. Probably i must control string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) but i didn't it. My code bellow. Please help me
Thank you everyone i solved this problem. Problem was not here. Prooblem in my route codes. for search is different i would write my route codes this

```js
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name:"search",
                pattern: "{search}",
                defaults: new {controller="Shop",action="search"}
               );
```

but not in from of pattern: "{search}
should be this pattern: "search"
Thank you to everyone who helped

```js
   public List<Product> GetSearchResult(string searchString)
        {
              using (var context = new ShopContext())
            {
                var products = context 
                .Products
                .Where(i=>  i.IsApproved && (i.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) ||  i.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()))) 
                .AsQueryable();
                
                return products.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add exception which was thrown.

Comment: With the inner exception.

Comment: This could be a case of trying to do too much in a single statement. Unless you can break this out into multiple processes, it's going to be really hard to know where your error is. If you could paste the FULL error, along with the stack trace, that would help.

Comment: the most possible cause is due to the `searchString` being null. You need to check if it's null first. Or simply normalize its value at the beginning like this `searchString = searchString ?? "";`

Comment: because this is related to `EFCore` you should tag it and state clearly its version (because it does matter a lot). As what I've tried, in EFCore 2.2.6, the code should be perfectly compiled and translated to SQL Query (`.ToLower().Contains(...)` is compiled fine). So as I commented above, the most possible exception to be thrown here is when `searchString` is null. However for the exception you described (in the title), looks like it's different. Not sure what kind of `EFCore` you're using or you may surely not post the other related code which actually causes the exception.

Comment: Thank you everyone i solved this problem. Problem was not here. Prooblem in my route codes. I changed and add above

Comment: you have broken everything, all the traces making all the below answers non-sense =)) nice try man. Next time, please keep your question intact. It's not where you can replace almost the whole content with your self-solved answer. You can post your own answer in a separate ***Answer*** as the others did. The purpose of Q&A is not just to help solve your own problem, the main purpose is to help solve the similar problems encountered by ***other developers*** as well. It means all the questions & answers may help many guys, not just you this time.

Comment: sorry you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I would break this up as follows:

```
public List<Product> GetSearchResult(string searchString)
{
   // What do you want to do if searchString is null or blank? (Pick one:)

   // You could send back an empty result...
   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
      return null;

   // Or you could convert it to a blank string
   if (searchString == null)
       searchString = "";

   List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

    using (var context = new ShopContext())
    {
        products = context.Products.ToList();
    }

    // Always check for null and empty after going to the DB
    if (products == null || products.count = 0)
        return null;

   // If we are still here, then we can finally do the search
   List<Product> results = products.Where(i=> i.IsApproved && 
        (i.Name != null && i.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) ||
        (i.Description != null && i.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())));

   return results;
}
```

Note: I've not tested this and there may be syntax errors in the last LINQ statement with all of the ('s and )'s.

**EDIT:**

The example above will pull back ALL records in the `Product` table and then filter the results in-memory. If you want to avoid that, then I think this should work:

```
public List<Product> GetSearchResult(string searchString)
{
   // What do you want to do if searchString is null or blank? (Pick one:)

   // You could send back an empty result...
   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
      return null;

   // Or you could convert it to a blank string
   if (searchString == null)
       searchString = "";

    using (var context = new ShopContext())
    {
        List<Product> products = context.Products.Where(i=> i.IsApproved && 
        (i.Name != null && i.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) ||
        (i.Description != null && i.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()))).ToList();

       return products;
    }
}
```

The key difference between this and your OP is that we are checking for null's on `Name` and `Description` -- and I *believe* this does it in a way that EF can translate into a query.

Comment: Okay, i don't know a lot about EF. But `i.Name` or `i.Description` could still be `null` and throw an exception when trying to call `ToLower` on them which would cause the LINQ to fail.

Comment: @MichaelChen, good point! I will fix. In my answer. By the time the search is being done, we are outside of EF and we're just working with an in-memory list. The trip to the database happened with `products = context.Products.ToList()` which gets translated into a query. In this case, the query is "SELECT * FROM Products".

Comment: Just to note that loading all records and then filtering in memory kills the benefit of the expression tree. Especially if there are many products.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, yes, thus my edit. (refresh the page?)

Comment: Ah, gotchya :-)

Answer (score -1):

Not a lot of information at hand but i assume the LINQ fails because a string is null.
Also why do you create a queryable of your results and then produce a list?

```cs
public List<Product> GetSearchResult(string searchString) {
    static bool Contains(string a, string b) {
        return a.ToLower().Contains(b.ToLower());
    }

    using (var context = new ShopContext()) {
        return context
        .Products
        .Where(i => i.IsApproved)
        .Where(i => i.Name is null ? false : Contains(i.Name, searchString)
        || i.Description is null ? false : Contains(i.Description, searchString))
        .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: This inner function will throw as there is no translation of it to sql.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I dont understand what you mean. What does this code have to do with SQL?

Comment: Shop context looks like EF context that translates the expression tree into a query.

Comment: Wiktor is right. `context` is an Enterprise Framework representation of the database, and any LINQ query needs to translate into SQL

Comment: Thank you everyone i solved this problem. Problem was not here. Prooblem in my route codes. I changed and add above